# Sharing to Facebook shows error "We are Sorry, this post is no longer available. It may have been removed"

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to implement Facebook sharing in my game using Unity 3D + Facebook Unity SDK. But when I tried testing to post to my wall, this error shows up: "We are Sorry, this post is no longer available. It may have been removed." Can anybody help me? Thanks in advance.

BTW, here's my code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class FacebookController : MonoBehaviour {

    public bool isUsingFacebook = true; //Are we using Facebook SDK? This variable is only 

    //Feed parameters.
    private string link = "market://details?id=com.LaserCookie.Queue"; //The link that will show the user the game's google play store address
    private string linkName = "Queue"; //The link name
    private string linkCaption = "Wow this game is great! 10/10 must play!"; // The caption of the link
    private string linkDescription = "I achieved the score of " + PlayerController.instance.score.ToString() + "! Try to beat me if you can!"; //The description of the link
    private string picture = "http://www.drycreekequestriancenter.com/testImage.jpeg"; //This is the image / game icon for the link. For now, it's shamelessly got from a random source. Thank you, random citizen...

    void Awake()
    {

    }

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }

    //Init FB
    private void Init()
    {
        if (!FB.IsInitialized)
        {
            FB.Init(OnInitComplete, OnHideUnity);
        }

    }

    //Callback that will be called when the initialization is completed
    private void OnInitComplete()
    {
        Debug.Log("FB.Init completed: Is user logged in? " + FB.IsLoggedIn);

        //Check if we are logged in. 
        //If not, we will log in.
        //If we are, post status.
        if (!FB.IsLoggedIn)
        {
            LoginWithPublish();
        }
        else
        {
            PostImpl();
        }
    }

    //Callback that will be called when the game is shown / not
    private void OnHideUnity(bool isGameShown)
    {
        Debug.Log("Is game showing? " + isGameShown);
    }

    //Post to Facebook. This is the only exposed method because we only use this to post to Facebook.
    //The initialization and login will be called when needed.
    //It will first detect whether or not we have been initialized. And will init if we haven't.
    //Then it will check whether or not we have been logged in with publish. And will log in if not.
    public void PostToFacebook()
    {
        //Are we using facebook SDK?
        if (isUsingFacebook)
        {

            if (!FB.IsInitialized) //Check for initialization
            {
                Init();
            }
            else if (!FB.IsLoggedIn) //Check for login
            {
                LoginWithPublish();
            }
            else //Post if we are already initia;ized and logged in
            {
                PostImpl();
            }
        }
    }

    //The true implementation of the posting
    private void PostImpl()
    {
        FB.Feed("",link, linkName,linkCaption,linkDescription,picture);
    }


    //Login to Facebook with publish 
    private void LoginWithPublish()
    {
        // It is generally good behavior to split asking for read and publish
        // permissions rather than ask for them all at once.
        //
        // In your own game, consider postponing this call until the moment
        // you actually need it.
        FB.Login("publish_actions", LoginCallback);
    }

    //Login callback
    void LoginCallback(FBResult result)
    {
        if (result.Error != null)
        {
            Debug.Log( "Error Response:\n" + result.Error );

            //TODO: Retry login if we have error? Or do we display a pop up?
        }
        else if (!FB.IsLoggedIn)
        {
            Debug.Log( "Login cancelled by Player" );

            //TODO: Do we display a pop up?
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log( "Login was successful!" );

            PostImpl();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't think that it has got anything to do with my code. Maybe it's just some settings error (since this is my first attempt to use Facebook SDK). I practically copied the example scripts. But nevertheless, I'll edit the question and put my code.

Comment: BTW, for the settings in the Facebook dashboard, I haven't submitted the app for approval. No other settings besides the Settings/Basic/Android. And also, I haven't submitted it in the Google Play Store. Is that the case?

Comment: then thats authentication error. you must submit your app in facebook developer. for submitting in google play, that's not the case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've fixed the issue. It turns out it's because I used my still in development google store address as the link. I thought it would be automatically recognized regardless of my app is live or not. Thank you anyway. :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add Key Hash for FB application.

Go to My Apps, select you application, open Setting tab, add platform for android, and add you key hash.

check this link out
[Setting a Release Key Hash](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started#release-key-hash)

Comment: Sorry, I think I've managed to fix the issue. But I couldn't check it for answer back then because I needed to wait for 24 hours. And then I forgot all about it. Thanks again.